# How does NHibernate's 2nd level cache work with a connection provider?

Tags: nhibernate

I understand that NHibernate's 2nd level cache works at the SessionFactory level. I'm using a connection provider in my NHibernate configuration to work with my multi-tenant environment. I'm wondering how the 2nd level cache interacts with the connection provider. That is, does it intelligently maintain a cache for each separate connection string, or do all connections share the same cache?

Obviously sharing the same cache is a huge no-no since the same query will return different results based on the database it is hitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The life time of the second level cache is tied to the session factory and not to an individual session. Once an entity is loaded by its unique id and the second level cache is active the entity is available for all other sessions (of the same session factory).

So 2nd level works only thru sessions of the same session factory.

Please look [First and Second Level caching in NHibernate](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate) for more details

Comment: Thanks. I have already read that article but since it didn't specifically mention the connection providers I was hoping there might be an exception. Unfortunately connection providers appear to be completely incompatible with the 2nd level cache because of this.

Comment: yep, the same able to see in nhibernate profiler. It's able to monitor only session's calls.